How to scale axis in pgfplots
How can I conveniently scale an axis or set a ratio of the axis in pgfplots to display the entire graph?
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}     
    \begin{axis}[set layers,axis background ,
        title style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north,yshift=-0.1}, 
        restrict y to domain=-100:100,
        samples=301, 
        axis lines=middle,
        axis equal image,
        %no marks,
        axis line style={very thick, draw=black},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        enlarge y limits={rel=0.13},
        enlarge x limits={rel=0.07},
        legend style={at={(0.5,-0.1)},anchor=north},
        grid=both,
        ymin = -4,
        ymax = 4,
        xmin = -4,
        xmax = 4,
        extra x ticks=0,
        extra x tick style={
            tick label style={
                anchor=north east,
            }
        },
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=1.2pt,draw=gray!50},
        enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
        minor grid style={white!75!black}
        ]
        \addplot [
        domain=-4:4,
        smooth,ultra thick,
        ]{4*x^(3)-10*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Change or remove ymax, ymin. See https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-scaling#sec-4.10.1 for changing total dimensions of plot.

That is a starting point. Removing ymin/max causes it to collapse though. Geogebra allows a simple x:y ratio. Is there nothing equivalent?

axis equal image was a cause preventing the scaling.

See also scale only axis together with width and height.

pgfplots will scale the axes by default. You can specify width to make the plot bigger or smaller and maintain the default aspect-ratio. You can override the aspect-ratio by also specifying height.
In your code you set axis image equal = true, this tells pgfplot to ensure a 1 unit increase in the x-axis is the same distance as a 1 unit increase on the y-axis. domain = -4:4, specifies 8 units along the x-axis, this corresponds to a range between -216 and 216 on the y-axis (calculated by inserting -4 and 4 into the plotted function). As the domain differs greatly from the range and you've set each unit along both axes to be the same size you get a compressed appearance.
If you look at the graph below a 1 unit increase on the x-axis corresponds to a 100 unit increase on the y-axis.
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=$y$,
    axis lines= middle,
    domain=-4:4,
    width = 12cm,
]

\addplot{4*x^(3)-10*x};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Result:


You should define domain of function and told why you omit axis equal image, ... anyway, nice answer (+1)

@Zarko Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer to reflect your improvements.
